# Can't produce dates between two given dates keeping leading zero intact

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to produce all the dates between two dates. What I've written so far can produce the dates flawlessly but It kicks out leading zeros from months and days.

I've tried with:

```
Sub GenerateCustomizedDates()
    Dim FirstDate As Date, LastDate As Date, DateIter As Date
    
    FirstDate = "01/01/2012"
    LastDate = "01/30/2012"
    
    For DateIter = FirstDate To LastDate
        R = R + 1: Cells(R, 2) = Replace(DateIter, "/", "_")
    Next DateIter
End Sub
```

Output I'm having are like:

```
1_1_2012
1_2_2012
1_3_2012
1_4_2012
```

Output I wish to have:

```
01_01_2012
01_02_2012
01_03_2012
01_04_2012
```

How can I achieve the format of latter output using vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Range.NumberFormat` to apply the date format (escaping the underscore `_` with a backslash `\`). [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/replace-function) returns a `String`; better to just apply the date formatting directly after writing the values to the sheet.

```vb
For DateIter = FirstDate To LastDate
    Dim R As Long
    R = R + 1: Cells(R, 2) = DateIter
Next DateIter

Range("B1:B" & R).NumberFormat = "mm\_dd\_yyyy"
```

I personally wouldn't do this, but you could also use `Format(DateIter, "mm\_dd\_yyyy")`.